# The best way to initialize a bean in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, beanshell

What would be the best (both human readable and fastest in runtime (say, compiled)) way to initialize a bean in Camel?

I need a bean to send it to JPA endpoint. The input is a Map created out of CSV. Looks like a trivial task, but I have just started with Camel, please help.

Currently I have managed to transform a Map into a more complicate Map that has the same strucure as my beans. I could write my own code that would traverse it, instantiate the lists and the lists members, employing Apache Beanutils, but I think there should be a faster way to initialize a bean right from the original Map, without creating an intermediate Map.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    <route id="AgencyCsvInput" errorHandlerRef="agencyDeadLetters">
        <from uri="direct:agencyCsvInput"/>
        <split streaming="true">
            <method ref="csvSplitter" method="tokenizeReader"/>  <!-- prepends the first line of file for every subsequent line -->
            <log message="splitted: ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
            <setHeader headerName="inputRegistryLines">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <unmarshal>
                <csv delimiter=";"  useMaps="true" />
            </unmarshal>            
            <log message="unmarshalled: size: ${body.size()}, ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
            <filter>
                <simple>${body.size()} == 1</simple><!-- be sure to have spaces around an operator -->
                <log message="filtered: listItem: ${body[0]['PATRONYMIC']}, list: ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
                <setProperty propertyName="parser">
                    <simple>ref:patternParser</simple>
                </setProperty>
                <transform>
                    <spel><![CDATA[#{
{
    dateOpen: properties['parser'].date(body[0]['ACTIVATION_DATE'], 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'),
    balances: {
        balance: {
            {
                typeCd: 'loanAmount',
                amount: properties['parser'].comma(body[0]['GRANTED_CREDIT']),
                currencyCd: body[0]['CURRENCY']
            },
            {
                typeCd: 'fee',
                amount: properties['parser'].comma(body[0]['Коммиссии']),
                currencyCd: body[0]['CURRENCY'],
                comment: 'Коммиссии'
            },
            {
                typeCd: 'fine',
                amount: properties['parser'].comma(body[0]['Пени']),
                currencyCd: body[0]['CURRENCY'],
                comment: 'Пени'
            },
            {
                typeCd: 'penalty',
                amount: properties['parser'].comma(body[0]['Штрафы']),
                currencyCd: body[0]['CURRENCY'],
                comment: 'Штрафы'
            }
        }
    },
    persons: {
        {
            typeCd: 'mainParty',
            person: {
                {
                    typeCd: 'individual',
                    names: {
                        name: {
                            {
                                typeCd: 'currentName',
                                lastName: body[0]['LAST_NAME'],
                                firstName: body[0]['FIRST_NAME'],
                                middleName: body[0]['PATRONYMIC']
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    birthDate: properties['parser'].date(body[0]['BIRTH_DATE'], 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'),
                    contacts: {
                        contact: {
                            {
                                typeCd: 'residentialAddress',
                                technologyCd: 'physical',
                                relationCd: 'home',
                                address: body[0]['COMMENTS']
                            },
                            {
                                typeCd: 'officeAddress',
                                technologyCd: 'physical',
                                relationCd: 'work',
                                address: body[0]['COMMENTS_WORK']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
                        }]]></spel>
                </transform>                
                <log message="transformed: ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
                <to uri="direct:objectToDb"/>          
            </filter>
        </split>
    </route>
```

See how easy it is to transform a Map in a legible way, with just a couple of custom dates and number parser functions and SpEL inline Map/List instantiate syntax. It workedlike a charm when I had Hibernate "dynamic maps", so that my persistent objects were really the java.util.Maps. I'd wish to have the same easy way to instantiate a bean. It has some fields of List type, the type of listed objects is known, and they in turn may have other lists as their fields - all of them are based on beans with getters and setters.

Probably, the BeanShell has an inline bean initializing syntax? Or Camel has a way to invoke getters/setters and read the Map?

I want to avoid of scripting like this:

```
result = new myBean();
result.dateOpen = properties['parser'].date(body[0]['ACTIVATION_DATE'], 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');
balances = new Balances();
result.balances = balances;
balance = new List<Balance>();
reallyBalance = new Balance();
balance.add(balance);
reallyBalance.typeCd="loanAmount";
....
```

I find it ilegible.

It's a pure Camel question, but I'll mark it as Beanshell as well, hoping for hints of inline bean init syntax like:

```
bean = new MyBean(){dateOpen= properties['parser'].date(body[0]['ACTIVATION_DATE'], 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm')....};
```